# How to achieve 75% code coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Hi below are the class and test class.

Apex Class:

```
global class GE_PRM_Count_Active_Partner_Users implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Set<Integer> partnerCount = new Set<Integer>();
        List<User> partnerUsers = new List<User>();
        List<AggregateResult> groupPartnerAccs = new List<AggregateResult>();        
        Map<Id,Account> partnerAccounts = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, GE_PRM_Active_PRM_Users__c FROM Account WHERE IsPartner = true]);
        system.debug('*****HelooPartnerAccs***'+partnerAccounts.size());    
        groupPartnerAccs = [select AccountId,count(id) partnercount from User WHERE IsActive = true AND AccountId IN: partnerAccounts.keySet() AND AccountId != null group by AccountId];
        system.debug('Hi*****'+groupPartnerAccs.size());

        if ( groupPartnerAccs.size() > 0 ) {
            for ( AggregateResult agg : groupPartnerAccs ) {
                system.debug('*****aggpartneraccId*****'+(partnerAccounts.get(String.valueOf(agg.get('AccountId')))));
                if ( partnerAccounts.get(String.valueOf(agg.get('AccountId'))) != null ) {
                    partnerAccounts.get(String.valueOf(agg.get('accountId'))).GE_PRM_Active_PRM_Users__c = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(agg.get('partnercount'))); 
                    system.debug('***partnerActiveUserNo***'+partnerAccounts.get(String.valueOf(agg.get('accountId'))).GE_PRM_Active_PRM_Users__c);
                }
            }
            update partnerAccounts.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class GE_PRM_Count_Active_Partner_Users_Test {

    static testMethod void GE_PRM_Count_Active_Partner_UsersTestMethod(){
        Test.startTest();

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
        User u2 = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email='newuser@testorg.com', 
                        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='newuser@testorg.com');
        insert u2;

        System.runAs(u2) {
            account acc=new account();
            acc.GE_PRM_Active_PRM_Users__c=1;    
            acc.name='testacc';
            acc.GE_HQ_Request_Status__c='New';
            acc.GE_PW_Phone_New_Request__c='123456789';
            acc.GE_HQ_New_Account_Street__c='Room 203, Building Nanxuefu Garden, Zhaowuda Rd.';
            acc.GE_HQ_New_Account_City__c='Huhehaote';
            acc.GE_HQ_New_Account_State_Province__c='Inner Mongolia';
            acc.GE_HQ_New_Account_Zip_Postal_Code__c='010040';
            acc.GE_HQ_New_Account_Country__c='CHINA';
            acc.IsPartner =true;
           // IspersonAccount=true;
            insert acc;
                    //sch.execute(acc );
            GE_PRM_Count_Active_Partner_Users sh1 = new GE_PRM_Count_Active_Partner_Users();    
            String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
            system.schedule('Test Job', sch, sh1); 
       }    
       Test.stopTest();
    } 
}
```

I am not getting 75 can u please tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help reaching 100% coverage](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/help-reaching-100-coverage)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Debug log, does it show any records being returned from the second query?  It looks like you are never assigning the Account to the User.

By doing the System.runAs(User) method your Account will be Owned by the User, but I don't believe the User AccountId field will be set.

Try pulling your Account creation code out of the Test.startTest() / Test.stopTest() section and put it earlier.  Then after you've inserted the Account set the User.AccountId field to the Account Id, and update the User.

Then you can do your Test.startTest() / Test.stopTest() with the Scheduleable class in nested in it.