# Need to cover upto 85%

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, error-messages

I written a test class for one class.I am getting 83%. I want to cover 85% or above 85%. can you please help me out to cover 85%.
Below are the class and test class.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help reaching 100% coverage](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/help-reaching-100-coverage)

Comment: You don't have any test cases for when bpartnerUser is true, you should try to start writing one and edit this question if you get stuck on something more specific.

Comment: The cheapest workaround I've seen was adding bunch (what I saw was hundreds, leave puzzled us for a bit) of y=y; lines and then asserting them in test class. This will balloon your overall coverage, but use this only for extreme situations where there is just no time to properly write your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another three test method using remaining three Profile which is used in Controller.
So, Below code will be cover:

```
parnerprof = [Select Id from Profile where Name in ('Channel Partner DR/VAR/Reseller user','Channel Partner Leader user - DR','Channel Partner Leader user - SR','Channel Partner Sales Rep user')];
for(Profile p : parnerprof){

if(p.id==userprofileId){
    **bpartnerUser=true;**
}


errorMessage = '';

try {
    update branchOffice;            
}**catch(Exception e){
    errorMessage = 'Please Fill in Required Detail';
}**

if(errorMessage.length() >1){   
    **return null;** 
}
```

Comment: Hi sandip I am not able get you can you please change the method and post me plesae so that i can test it.

Comment: Find this below line in test method (Testsubdealerclass2):
 
 Profile p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Channel Partner Leader user - SR']; 
 
 and Change Profile Name using below three Profile,
 1. Channel Partner Leader user - DR
 2. Channel Partner Leader user - SR
 3. Channel Partner Sales Rep user
 
 and Create three another test method like "Testsubdealerclass2".

Comment: In my test class its already Profile p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Channel Partner Leader user - DR'];  like this

Comment: And Need to create another 3 test methods? means total 5?

Comment: Yes create total 5 method, 
and use other profile which is used in Controller of below code: 
parnerprof = [Select Id from Profile where Name in ('Channel Partner DR/VAR/Reseller user','Channel Partner Leader user - DR','Channel Partner Leader user - SR','Channel Partner Sales Rep user')];

Comment: I added that methods are failed can you please give me your email so that i will mail you please its urjent.

Comment: I mailed u can u please check it.